# How to create a keyboard shortcut for playing youtube videos with mpv?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal, mpv, xclip

I'm using Pop OS. I've aliased the command `mpv $(xclip -o) & exit` to `pp` so I can play youtube links copied to my clipboard with mpv player in lesser keystrokes in the terminal.
I realised I may also do this without even having to open the terminal by creating a 'custom shortcut'(in Pop OS keyboard settings) for the aforementioned command.

My attempt at the solution - I tried to assign the custom keys to `gnome-terminal -- mpv $(xclip -o)` and when it didn't work out I shortened it to `mpv $(xclip -o)` but with no success. Nothing happened after I pressed the assigned shortcut keys.

The question - How do I create a system-wide custom keyboard shortcut to play youtube videos with mpv with help of the command `mpv $(xclip -o) & exit` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `gnome-terminal -- bash -c` instead of just `gnome-terminal`.

Then you can create the shortcut.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It didn't work. The terminal opens up and then nothing happens. There's no text on it, nothing. I checked if xclip was working fine by typing 'xclip -o' in the terminal and it gives back the copied URL as expected, so no problem there. The mpv player is installed fine.